# Why does cout << *s << endl produce a segfault?

Tags: c++

I have this question on a practice exam for my C++ class, we're supposed to write what the output is or if it produces an error. Running this code produces a segmentation fault, but can someone explain why? It looks fine to me.

```
    string *s;
    s = (string *) "This is my house. I have to defend it.";
    cout << *s << endl;
```

Comment: Something like it's a temporary object on the second string

Comment: The C-style cast, `(string *)`, allows you do do anything, no matter how stupid. With it you can fit the round peg in the square hole. It turns off all of the protections the compiler has to prevent errors and says, I know what i am doing. You have to be absolutely certain that you are correct or the code produced will be nonsense.

Comment: "*It looks fine to me*" - then you are lacking a fundamental understanding of C++ basics, like the difference between a string literal and an object pointer. This is a prime example of why you should NOT use C style casts in C++. Omitting the cast, or using a C++ style cast, would have emitted a compiler error instead of causing a runtime error.

Comment: It's my first C++ class, I had a question. I *know* I'm lacking an understanding, that's why I asked it. The professor wrote this code, I wouldn't have written it like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indirecting through a pointer of type `std::string*` when it doesn't point to an object of type `std::string` has undefined behaviour.

A string literal is not an object of type `std::string`. String literal is an array of characters. `std::string` is a class defined in the header `<string>`.

> Running this code produces a segmentation fault, but can someone explain why?

You indirect through a pointer that doesn't point to an object of compatible type. The behaviour of your program is undefined.

---

P.S. It is never necessary to use C-style cast (such as `(type)expression`). It can easily suppress helpful compilation errors and replace them with undefined behaviour. It should be avoided.

If you hadn't used a C-style cast here, then the type system would have alerted you to the mistake before getting to run the program. In this case, you might have seen an error message similar to:

```
error: cannot convert 'const char [39]' to 'std::string*' {aka 'std::basic_string<char>*'} in assignment
```

helping you realise that the types do not match.

Comment: Yes, this is undefined behavior, but the OP is getting a segmentation fault. Wouldn't that be because `s` doesn't have any memory allocated in it? While I suppose anything can happen in UB, wouldn't writing to allocated memory create a segmentation fault?

Comment: @Chipster There are many reasons for a segfault. Even reading from memory that does not exist will cause a segfault.

Comment: But here we are passing a reference to a string to `operator<<(std::ostream&, std::string const&)` where that reference is not really a string. Calling `operator<<()` may result in segfault if the reference is not aligned correctly. The function may call member functions for a string (segfault). The function is trying to access the members of string and the resulting member reference may not even be aligned correctly (segfault), the values retrieved may point at memory that does not exist, reading these pointer to get the string data (segfault). So many ways it could go wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn the difference between a [string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) and class [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

Casting a string literal to `std::string*` is undefined behaviour. Which manifests itself here as a segmentation fault when the code does `*s` because `s` is invalid.

Without that C-style cast `(string *)` in `s = (string *) "T...";` the compiler would emit an error.

Always question those C-style casts in C++.

Answer (score 0):

The likely problem (or at least one of the problems) is the fact that s has no memory allocated to it. You need to use the new keyword and try something like this:

```
string *s;
s = new string("This is my house. I have to defend it.");
cout << *s << endl;
```

Of course, in theory you'd need to use delete too.

Answer (score -1):

std::string tends to boil down to something that looks like this:

```
struct string
{
  char* _begin;
  char* _end;
  char* _capacity;
};
```

The text string you have defined would look like this:

```
const char* const text = "This is my house. I have to defend it."
```

So you are casting from type (char*), to type (string*). This now means that _begin will store the memory location **"This is "**, and _end will store the memory location **"my house"**

When printing the string to std::cout, it will dereference the pointer to s, and try to find the string size, usually implemented like so:

```
size_t string::size() const { return _end - _begin; }
```

Given that _begin and _end aren't storing pointer values (they are just random bits of text), this will result in cout trying to print a very wrong number of characters _(because the memory locations in _begin and *end are a nonsense)*

Comment: `std::vector` does look like that indeed. Not my downvote.

Comment: This is possible behaviour, but since the behaviour is undefined, it could also cause a rain of cream cheese.